# Eliminate characters in a string and convert it in float64 with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

fellows,

I am trying to eliminate some characters in a Object column in a Pandas dataframe, in order to convert it to int64 and make some calculations. The specific column has population (column **"populacaoTCU2019"**) values but, as some values were listed wrongly as 10.320(2), 23.320(14), 43.223(23), etc, I need to eliminate the "." (*which I think it can be done with str.replace(".","")*). But the values in the parenthesis are more complicate, as the values vary through the rows. Can anyone give me a help on this matter?

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 617658 entries, 4145 to 624062
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column                  Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------                  --------------   -----                
 9   populacaoTCU2019        617658 non-null  object        
  
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(5), int64(6), object(5)
memory usage: 84.8+ MB
```

And I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-4b87875ecf91> in <module>
      1 #vamos criar uma coluna nova para indicar o valor dividido pela população. Mas precisa converter os dados de objet e int64 em float64
      2 #Para as cidades
----> 3 df_cidades['novos_obitos_rel'] = 100000*df_cidades['obitosNovos'].astype('float64')/df_cidades['populacaoTCU2019'].astype('float64')
      4 df_cidades['obitos_acum_rel'] = 100000*df_cidades['obitosAcumulado'].astype('float64')/df_cidades['populacaoTCU2019'].astype('float64')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5696         else:
   5697             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5698             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
   5699             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   5700 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    580 
    581     def astype(self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"):
--> 582         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    583 
    584     def convert(self, **kwargs):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, filter, **kwargs)
    440                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    441             else:
--> 442                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    443             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    444 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    623             vals1d = values.ravel()
    624             try:
--> 625                 values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
    626             except (ValueError, TypeError):
    627                 # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    895     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
    896         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 897         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    898 
    899     return arr.view(dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '32.105(2)'
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: If I eliminate the "." and the parenthesis and the value inside (XX), I can convert it to a int64 and do calculations, like dividing it with another column.

Comment: Float or integer? Your question mentions float, but your comment (and examples) mention integer values.

Comment: I assume the dot is a thousand separator, and the values inside the parentheses are errors?

Comment: My bad. I mean Integer. I converted it to int64. And the decimal is not a decimal separator. It is some type of error in the data.